# How can I make one view in Qt display checkboxes while the other does not?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have two views in Qt. Both use a model derived from QAbstractListModel.

I would like to show a checkbox in only one of the two views. Is this possible without creating an entirely new view class? I use C++.

I tried creating a new view class that is derived from my main view class and where only the flags() function is overridden. The idea was that both views would use the same model object but one view would call flags() in the base class whereas the other would call flags() in the derived class. But the derived class ends up being used in both cases.

Comment: Derive a class from `QIdentityProxyModel`, override `flags()` to suppress `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` flag. Give one of the views this model, wrapping the underlying "real' model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control how a view accesses `flags()` (nor you should try to).

As suggested in the comments, you could use a QIdentityProxyModel, but overriding [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) won't suffice, and [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) must be overridden too.

When `flags()` returns the source flags *without* the `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` it will only prevent the user to check the item, but the check box will still be visible as long as a `CheckStateRole` value is set, which is reasonable: as the name suggests, that flag only tells if the item is "checkable by the user", but the model may still need to show check boxes for displaying purposes.

In order to completely hide the check box, `data()` should return `QVariant()` whenever the `role` is `Qt::CheckStateRole`.

In reality, the implementation of `data()` alone should be enough, but overriding `flags()` would be more safe, appropriate and consistent.

I won't attempt to write bad C++ code, but the following Python example should be clear enough:

```py
class Proxy(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            # in C++ this would be "return QVariant()", it's also possible
            # in PySide/PyQt but actually unnecessary as it is considered
            # implicit in this context.
            return

        # for any other role, return what the source model's data() would
        return super().data(index, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        # get the default result from flags() and return it by removing
        # the unwanted flag in the meantime
        return super().flags(index) & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
```

Alternatively, you can use an item delegate that overrides [`initStyleOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) and unsets the `HasCheckIndicator` flag from the option's [`feature`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#features-var), which has an effect similar to what `data()` did above, but in this case we have the opposite problem: "hiding" the check state only prevents toggling it using the mouse (because there's no visible check indicator to click), but checkable items can also be toggled using the keyboard (with <kbd>Space bar</kbd> or the <kbd>Select</kbd> key that some keyboards and input devices have), so you should also ensure that [`editorEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemdelegate.html#editorEvent) doesn't handle keyboard events that may trigger the check state toggling anyway:

> The base implementation returns false (indicating that it has not handled the event).

In this case, the space/select keys are eventually used by the view to start editing the index (assuming that the model is writable and the view's edit triggers allow it).

As above, a basic example of how this can be achieved in Python:

```py
class NoCheckDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        # set up the option based on the index
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        # remove the check indicator flag to prevent both displaying it and
        # possible mouse interaction normally used for toggling it
        opt.features &= ~opt.HasCheckIndicator

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, opt, index):
        if (
            event.type() == event.KeyPress and (
                event.key() == Qt.Key_Space 
                or event.key() == Qt.Key_Select
            )
        ):
            # "ignore" the event and let the view handle it if possible
            return False
        # just do anything else as expected from the delegate
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, opt, index)
```